# Split CSV by date

Tags: python, date, csv

I'm hoping that there is a relatively simple solution to my problem:

I have a csv with a selection of data points but they all include a date field.

I would like to be able to split up the csv into multiple files based on the month of the date field.

For example:  I would like to be able to have all the records before March 2015 in 1 file, all before April 2015 in another, up to all before October 2016 etc.

In this case there will be many duplicate records between the files.

Is there a way to do this with a simple bit of python code or is there an easier method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rest assured you can do it with python :)
Joke aside, what have you done so far and can you share example of data?

Comment: At the moment I've been trying to do it manually in delimiter, problem is I have over 2 million records which makes it very difficult to share. It's house sale data over a 15 year period with a "price paid" field, "date of sale", "coordinates" etc.

Comment: Word of advice - never share actual data. On the other hand it is essential that you share example of your data for anyone to be able to help you or give you advice. Slice of 5 rows with data formatted the same way as your source would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes that the date field is in the first column and is labelled "`dates`".  We use pandas to read in the data to a dataframe and pass `['dates']` as the column to convert to date objects.  We then take different slices of the dataframe using the year and month to create subsetted views.  Each view is then dumped to a new csv with the format `year_month.csv`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', parse_dates=['dates'])

for year in df.dates.apply(lambda x: x.year).unique():
    for month in df.dates.apply(lambda x: x.month).unique():
        view = df[df.dates.apply(lambda x: x.month == month and x.year==year)]
        if view.size:
            view.to_csv('{}_{:0>2}.csv'.format(year, month))
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but this will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for your help James. Running the code I'm getting the attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'  :  Is this to do with the format of my date in the field? It's currently dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: What is the header for the column of your dates?  That is what needs to be passed to the `parse_dates` keyword input.

Answer (score 0):

Updating this to include date_parser to solve the attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'year' issue.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], date_parser=pd.to_datetime)

for year in df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year).unique():
    for month in df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.month).unique():
        view = df[df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.month == month and x.year == year)]
        if view.size:
            view.to_csv('{}_{:0>2}.csv'.format(year, month), index=False)
```